# Logging to the database in Spring

Tags: database, logging

I have built a spring application with the dao,model, view, and controller layer.  For logging, I am using log4j. I want to log some things to the database..whats the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this one: write a custom appender which extends JDBC appender